# "Ghost" view appearing

Tags: ios, swift

To get cleaner look for my app, each cell in my table view has an extra view with the original one made to match the background. Each cell is also associated with a video in the documents folder. I have it setup so that the video can be renamed. However, as soon any video is renamed, a "ghost" view appears. I have absolutely no idea on why or even HOW this is possible. Here's where the name is changed:

```
do {

    var urlMOV = cell.videoURL!
    let JPGdelete = cell.urlJpg
    var valuesMOV = URLResourceValues.init()

    if ((alertAlCon.textFields!.first?.text?.characters.count)! >= 15){=


        let tmAlcon = UIAlertController(title: "Too Long", message: "The name you entered is too long", preferredStyle: .alert)

        let tmCancelAl = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: {action in

            self.present(alertAlCon, animated: true, completion: nil)
            })


        tmAlcon.addAction(tmCancelAl)
        self.present(tmAlcon, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

    if ((alertAlCon.textFields!.first?.text?.characters.count)! <= 14){

        valuesMOV.name = (alertAlCon.textFields!.first?.text)! + ".mp4"
        try urlMOV.setResourceValues(valuesMOV)
        try! FileManager().removeItem(at: JPGdelete!)
    }
}


catch {
    Swift.print("Error in rewrite ", error)
}
```

And this is where the extra view is made:

```
let rectangle = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: parent.view.frame.width, height: 88)
let myView : UIView = UIView(frame: rectangle)
myView.center = self.center
myView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
self.contentView.addSubview(myView)
self.contentView.sendSubview(toBack: myView)
```

Here's screenshots of what's going on:

[image: Before the name is changed]

[image: After the name is changed]

Does anyone have any idea on why this is happening????

Comment: try `Debug View Hierarchy`. If you don't know how to do that see this https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/debugging_with_xcode/chapters/special_debugging_workflows.html

Comment: where is extra code  written are it written in View will appear or similar

Comment: I get this error when I capture the views: "2017-08-21 20:52:19.542813-0700 MyApp[2698:799302] libMobileGestalt MobileGestaltSupport.m:153: pid 2698 (MyApp) does not have sandbox access for frZQaeyWLUvLjeuEK43hmg and IS NOT appropriately entitled
2017-08-21 20:52:19.542922-0700 MyApp[2698:799302] libMobileGestalt MobileGestalt.c:550: no access to InverseDeviceID (see <rdar://problem/11744455>)
(lldb)" BUT I am able to find out that the extra view is DUPLICATING! Will test further. And the extra view is written in a function in the cell that is called when the cell is init by the table view.

Comment: Ran out of space in last comment:) Thanks Bilal for the tip. I'm still new to Xcode and Swift, and this is the first time I remember hearing of the Debug View Hierarchy. This'll help a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Bilal's help, found that my extra view function was continually adding more views to my cell due to the way I have to reload the data in the table view. I was able to fix it by looking in the cell's subviews for my extra view's tag, and deleting that view if it was there. Here's the function:

```
func setViews(){

    let selectedView = UIView()
    selectedView.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(red: 0.0/255.0, green: 75.0/255.0, blue: 150.0/255.0, alpha: 0.25)
    self.selectedBackgroundView = selectedView

    if let viewWithTag = self.contentView.viewWithTag(821){

        viewWithTag.removeFromSuperview()

    }

    let rectangle = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: parent.view.frame.width, height: 88)
    let myView : UIView = UIView(frame: rectangle)
    myView.center = self.contentView.center
    myView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    myView.tag = 821
    self.contentView.addSubview(myView)
    self.contentView.sendSubview(toBack: myView)

}
```